# How to share SessionAttributes between Controllers in Spring MVC?

Tags: session, spring-mvc, attributes

I would like to share Session Attributes betweet two Controllers in Spring MVC, using the @SessionAttributes annotation.

Here is a simple code I use to test the attributes sharing :

AController.java

```java
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("myParam")
public class AController {

@RequestMapping(value="/a")
public String handle(Model model){

    if(!model.containsAttribute("myParam"))
        model.addAttribute("myParam", randomInt());

    return "a";
}

private int randomInt(){
    return new Random().nextInt(100);
}

}
```

a.jsp

```jsp
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<h1>Page A</h1>
<p>Param = ${myParam}</p>
</html>
```

BController.java

```java
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("myParam")
public class BController {

@RequestMapping(value="/b")
public String handle(Model model){

    if(!model.containsAttribute("myParam"))
        model.addAttribute("myParam", randomInt());

    return "b";
}

private int randomInt(){
    return new Random().nextInt(100);
}

}
```

b.jsp

```jsp
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<h1>Page B</h1>
<p>Param = ${myParam}</p>
```

The behaviour I expect is to go to the /a URL, myParam would be set to a random value between 0 and 99, then this value would be shared between the two controllers.

However,what happens is the following:
I go to the /a URL, myParam is set to a value (let's say 10).
Then i go to the /b URL, myParam is set to another value (let's say 20).
When I go back to the /a URL, myParam value is the one set by the BController ( myParam =20).

Once the two controllers methods have been executed, the value is shared, but before, each controller redefines a new value.

It seems like if a Controller has never set a value to a SessionAttribute, it does not detect that attribute if it was set by another Controller.

I really would like to be able to share session attributes betwen controllers without using the HttpSession object and sticking with Spring MVC 3 objects.

I would like to know if I missed something or if there are other practices to share data in a session between controllers.

NB : the webapp was deployed on a Tomcat7 server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Spring MVC, @SessionAttributes are not meant to be shared accross Controllers.

What I did instead was to create an object (via a POJO) with the Session scope, that holds all the values I need to store for a Session.

I then use the JDK dynamic proxy to Autowire the object to the Controllers.

Comment: It'll be helpful if you can share how did you share the POJO using dynamic proxy autowiring.

Comment: @susithasenarath like this ....@Component(value="registerBean")
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "request")