# Maintain Model Data between Pages (Spring 3 MVC)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am having a add Contact process in Spring which will span across multiple pages, First Pages will take text Input, second Page will Take Image input and Third with Display the Draft.

First Page

```
@RequestMapping("/addContact")
public String registerContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
 return "addContact";
}
@RequestMapping("/addContact")
```

Second Page

```
@RequestMapping("/addImages")
public String registerImages(@Valid Contact contact, BindingResult result) {
 return "addImages";
}
```

How can I maintain contact model data between the pages so that, I can give option to user to move back and froth between the pages?

Comment: That depends... Do you have a single controller or multiple controllers.

Comment: You can use @SessionAttribute to maintain sessions and you can also put your objects in model.setAttribute("key","value") to set SessionAttributes.

Comment: M. Deinum , I have single controller for all pages

Comment: @Tushar Spring has a concept called Web Flow.

Comment: @Niks I am aware of that ,but I am trying do it without setting up a web flow , as these are just three pages, without much complexity

Comment: @Tushar mkyong has one such tutorial but that is without annotations.Nice Question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a single controller handling all the pages you can use `@SessionAttributes` to store the `Contact` between requests in the session. After the last page use `SessionStatus` to mark the use of the `@SessionAttribtues` complete (for cleanup).

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("contact")
public AddContactController {

    @ModelAttribute
    public Contact contact() {
        return new Contact();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/addContact")
    public String registerContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
        return "addContact";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/addImages")
    public String registerImages(@Valid @ModelAttribute Contact contact, BindingResult result) {
        return "addImages";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/save")    
    public String firstPage(@ModelAttribute Contact contact, SessionStatus status) {
      status.complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a single controller handling all the pages you can use @SessionAttributes....Can't you use same session attribute in multiple controllers?

Comment: I think your last request should be POST and using PRG design pattern also?Isn't it?

Comment: @SessionAttributes is not intended to store data in the session between controllers, it should only be used for a single controller! (At one point the naming for `@SessionAttributes' for storing the attributes in the session was bound to the controller name). So only use it for a single controller. Regarding the requests I think they al shuould be posts and then a redirect to the next screen should be issued. But that is IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using @SessionAttributes which has one limitation [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401402/how-to-share-sessionattributes-between-controllers-in-spring-mvc).
This totally depends upon your design though.

or you can use below mention pesudocode.Check the Session API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

```
Use HttpServletRequest in your RequestMapping to get request.


HttpSession session = request.getSession();//make an 

session.setAttribute("user", userDTO);


try
{
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
if(session!=null)
{

UserDTO userDTO = (UserDTO) session.getAttribute("user");
```

}

where userDTO is your object

**HOW TO GO BACK AND FORTH IN FORM**

Now in Order to go back and forth in your Flow.You have to create forward and backward links and use the session to populate the already saved values.

If you need more specific code let me know.