# Spring preserve ModelAttribute between requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session-variables, modelattribute

I'm trying to achieve a loop of the following steps before save is called.

1. Show list
2. add to list

It works adding one item. On the second item added spring has lost the reference to the [`ModelAttribute`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) which contained an item already and tries to reconstruct it from the form data, which it must not because it contains polymorphic types.

How do I preserve the updated model throughout every add?

Sample

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show(@ModelAttribute("foos") ArrayList<Foo> foo, Map model) {
    model.put("foo", foo);
    return "foo.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addFoo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@ModelAttribute("foos") ArrayList<Foo> foo,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    foo.add(new FooImpl());
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("foos", foo);
    return "redirect:foo";
}
```

How can I do this without using [`SessionAttributes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781439/maintain-model-data-between-pages-spring-3-mvc)?

Comment: You basically need to use session attributes, in one way or another. Or persist and retrieve the object.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was afraid of that. Persist and retrieve essentially emulates session attributes. I'm thinking perhaps an [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html), aspects or some other mechanism could prove useful.

Comment: Why don't you want session attributes? Also, redirect attributes could work fine (they use session as well).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Because session attributes doesn't easily clear the state should the flow be interrupted. RedirectAttributes are what I'm using to no great success

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In my case there can be two tabs open for two users, I don't want  `session attributes`, [any suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48355807/3425489) ?