# How to manage/store request parameters for subsequent request in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I frequently use scenario as:

1. List users ( on ajax call )
   On a search page, after search button click with some **search criteria**., I have list of Users in jQuery datatable
2. Click to Edit User
   In datatable I click to edit user from list, I redirects to a form for User update populated with user fields for updating purpose.
3. Update User
   After successfully updating User, redirect to Search Page **with search criteria** from **1st Request**.

Currently I'm passing **Search criteria** parameters when I click to edit user in **2nd request**, store them as **hidden fields** in update user form, after update button click **3rd request** pass them to controller. If successful Update again pass them to Search Page to know **previous search criteria**.

Any other idea to **Know Previous Search Criteria** ?
Is using session is good solution or should I continue with my solution ?

**Update**
Now **request parameters** are encapsulate in **bean**.

Answer (score 0):

No don't use a session for this, will be confusing if you have multiple browser tabs open. You should just use Javascript code, if you need to use cookies so be it but you shouldn't even need that. This sort of stuff you will have less trouble if you put your front-end developer hat on instead of your backend.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm implementing front-end as well as back-end, BTW what JavaScript Code you suggest?

Comment: I don't know what frameworks you are using for javascript code, but just gogle cookies, that will probably be the easiest. I would suggest in the future, you look into not using templating and rather create only REST services in Spring, and then create a ReactApp/Angular which uses that API.