# How to make spring session persistent throughout multiple requests?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-session

I'm developing a web application using Spring Boot and Angular (in the background I'm also using Spring Session, Security and Data Jpa). I've  encountered a problem with the session. It seems like spring is creating a new session instance for each request (I checked the session id). My question is, is there any way to prevent this from happening? I would like to store values in a session and keep them persistent throughout requests.

This does not happen in a fresh project that only has a spring-boot-starter-web dependency.

Here is my controller showing the problem:

```java
@PostMapping("/set_item")
public void setItem(HttpSession session, @RequestParam String item) {
    System.out.println("Session Id " + session.getId());
    System.out.println("Item " + item);
    session.setAttribute("item", item);
    System.out.println("Session Item " + session.getAttribute("item"));
}

@GetMapping("/get_item")
public Object getItem(HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("Session Id " + session.getId());
    System.out.println("Session Attribute " + 
    session.getAttribute("item"));
    return session.getAttribute("item");
}
```

When I make a request using POSTMAN on "http://localhost:8181/set_item?item=Banana"
what I get in the console is

```
Session Id 424dda79-f7b1-4818-8bcc-d371b4a1b7d5
Item Banana
Session Item Banana
```

So as we can see the attribute is set correctly.

And my console log when I do a GET request on "http://localhost:8181/get_item"

```
Session Id e04f0de2-d7d2-4827-9652-3f6232b27c3f
Session Attribute null
```

So, a new instance is created.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm this behavior in browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Frank, when you are making a request via Postman, it always treat as a new request.

When you are using spring session and spring security, spring create new session after successful login.

Instead of testing application from Postman, deploy the application, run it, test it and analyze it.

It will definitely help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Now everything makes scene. Since I previously I used Basic Authentication with Postman, spring created a new session instance each time. Now I used Angular to send requests and the application worked as expected!

Answer (score 0):

If item is the value you'd like to store in the session then you can make use of Spring's @SessionAttributes

Assuming your controller looks similar:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("item")
@RequestMapping("/item")
public class ItemController {
...
}
```

This post might help [Maintain model data between sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781439/maintain-model-data-between-pages-spring-3-mvc)