# Why are in Spring MVC @SessionAttributes not meant to be shared across Controllers

Tags: spring-mvc, session

I am learning Spring Boot and I encountered quote that @SessionAttributes should not be shared across Controllers. Why is that?

I have read Spring documentation about @SessionAttributes and searched Google. Found only one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401402/how-to-share-sessionattributes-between-controllers-in-spring-mvc) on Stack overflow where it is mentioned, but without explanation why.